# How to call a function which is type predefined struct

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

this is my first time asking a question. The forums have been super helpful to me so I will try and only give you the juicy parts:

I have two functions, one is a Search function that searches a precreated binary search tree through pointers (I can display the search tree through a different function, so I know it's populated) for a specific value. It puts the info from that node into a predefined data structure Nubline with the same types of varaibles (int, float, and string), and then returns that data structure.

Here's my code:

```
struct node
{
    int id;
    string name;
    float balance;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
node *rootID, *rootName;

struct Nubline
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    float Amnt;
};
//Search function; the node is a pointer to a linked list with move id's node *left and node *right;    
Nubline SearchbyID(node* &t, int x)
{
    if (t != NULL)
    {
        if (t->id == x)
        {
            Nubline r;
            r.ID = t->id;
            r.Name = t->name;
            r.Amnt = t->balance;
            return r;
        }
        SearchbyID(t->left, x);
        SearchbyID(t->right, x);
    }
}
//function that calls the search function
void BalancebyID()
{
    int num;
    cout << "\tWhat is your ID number? "; cin >> num;
    Nubline duke = SearchbyID(rootID, num);
    cout << "\t\t"<< duke.Name << " your balance is $" << duke.Amnt;
}

void main()
{
//calling statement
    BalancebyID();
    system("pause");//pausing to view result
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT -1)) == 0
```

I think I've narrowed down the issue to the function initialization, because I can make the function void and it runs (without all the other code, of course). I can also void the function, set an arbitrary global variable of type Nubline and put it where the variable "r" is, and then use it in my BalancebyID function, but it just displays zero, so I can assume it's not populating.

Sorry for the long-winded post.

**Tl;dr: how do I create a function that returns a data structure?**

Comment: A function isn't a `struct`. A function **returns** a **value**, which has a type. Also, ditch whatever book taught `void main` - it's absolutely `int main`.

Comment: You could simplify your code by having `node` contain a `Nubline` instead of the same 3 members with slightly different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here's my solution:

I voided the function, used a global variable `Nubline r;` and set `t` to that as follows:

```
void SearchbyID(node* &t, int x)
{
    if (t != NULL);
    {
        if (t->id == x)
        {
            r.ID = t->id;
            r.Name = t->name;
            r.Amnt = t->balance;
        }
//I also changed this to make it more efficient and not throw an access violation up by the if(t->id == x) statement
        if (x < t->id)
        {
            SearchbyID(t->left, x);
        }
        if (x > t->id)
        {
            SearchbyID(t->right, x);
        }
    }
}
//PART B
//Option 1: show Balance when ID is given
void BalancebyID()
{
    int num;
    cout << "\tWhat is your ID number? "; cin >> num;
    SearchbyID(rootID, num);
    cout << "\t\t"<< r.Name << " your balance is $" << r.Amnt;
}
```

This is what worked for me. Thank you all for your solutions; it helped me isolate the problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure `SearchbyID` work properly, you should add `return` to all conditions.

Also, you could make the returning type `Nubline*` then you can return a `nullptr` to indicate nothing found.

```
Nubline* SearchbyID(node* t, int x)
{
    if(t == nullptr) return nullptr;

    //else
    if (t->id == x)
    {
        auto r = new Nubline();
        r->ID   = t->id;
        r->Name = t->name;
        r->Amnt = t->balance;
        return r;
    }

    auto pLeft = SearchbyID(t->left, x);
    if (pLeft) return pLeft;

    return SearchbyID(t->right, x);
    //return NULL if nothing found
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, return a `nullptr` value.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think in this case raw owning pointer definition make it easier to read.

Comment: From the current declaration, I would (wrongly) not `delete` returned pointer. smart pointer changes 2 lines and fixes declaration. `optional` would be a good alternative in fact.

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay, okay. As you wish.

Comment: Sorry, man but it's throwing an access reading violation in `BalancebyID()`, even after I change `duke` to a pointer and the `cout<<duke` statements to pointer statements. Any suggestions?